# Get all the classes with a specific annotation in a java project

Tags: java, spring, reflection, annotations

In my current spring project, I need read in my service class all classes with a specific custom annotation (`@MainForm`) and return a List> to the controller. The class which should be read are placed on the package `com.spring.loja.model`. Anyone knows a way to do that?

Comment: I would recommend annotation processing.

Comment: If you configure your application using the spring framework, it's easy to get all beans with a certain annotation. Read this blog post: https://web.archive.org/web/20141216203709/http://techo-ecco.com/blog/spring-custom-annotations/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `isAnnotationPresent()` reflection method

```
  // Get all classes
  List<Class> klasses = ..

  // Filter only those containing
  for(Class k : klasses) {
    if(k.isAnnotationPresent(MainForm.class)) ...
  }
```

Comment: Ok, but how I get all the classes?

Comment: thats another question make new one instead asking again in here